# How to get the header for each entry of json in AngularJS html file?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have data values present in json file like below:

```
$scope.entries = {
        "27": {
            "e": {
                "d": "v1",
                "r": "v2"
            }

        },
        "03": {
            "e": {
                "d": "v3 ",
                "r": "v4"
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to get the header value present for each entry (i.e 27 and 03) and display in one of columns for each row in my html table. I am trying through this but no result:

```
<table style="width:100%">
                            <tr>
                              <th>Code</th>
                              <th>Value</th> 
                              <th>      </th> 
                              <th>      </th> 
                              <th>      </th> 

                            </tr>
                       <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in entries">
                            <tr ng-repeat="y in entries[x]">
                                <td>
                                    <!--<need to display 27 here in first row then 03 in next row>-->
                                    {{x}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{y.e.d+' : '+ y.e.r}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#!errordetails"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>View Details</a><!--more details hyperlink with router functionality-->
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#!erroredit">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="">Delete</a>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                         </div>
                        </table>
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat` with `(key, value)`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in entries">
    <td> {{key}} </td> <!-- Displays 27 in first row -->
    ...
</tr>
```